Python griddata() and Matlab griddata(): different results at some grid points
While converting some (pretty big physics) Matlab code to Python, I have stumbled upon this situation. Python/Scipy's griddata() function gives different results than Matlab's counterpart griddata() when interpolating the same 2d scattered data.
Matlab example code:
% Sample points (x,y): 7x5=35 points
points = [-3., -2.; -2.25, -2.; -1.5, -2.; -0.75, -2.; 0., -2.; 0.75, -2.; 1.5, -2.;
    -3., -1.25; -2.25, -1.25; -1.5, -1.25; -0.75, -1.25; 0., -1.25; 0.75, -1.25; 1.5, -1.25;
    -3., -0.5; -2.25, -0.5; -1.5, -0.5; -0.75, -0.5; 0., -0.5; 0.75, -0.5; 1.5, -0.5;
    -3., 0.25; -2.25, 0.25; -1.5, 0.25; -0.75, 0.25; 0., 0.25; 0.75, 0.25; 1.5, 0.25;
    -3., 1.; -2.25, 1.; -1.5, 1.; -0.75, 1.; 0., 1.; 0.75, 1.; 1.5, 1.]

% Data values at the sample points: 35 values
values = [0.12702104; -0.24534877; -0.08879096; 0.13749533; 0.2431933; -0.01159269; 0.11705169;
    0.10039714; 0.23370454; 0.0020298; -0.05512349; -0.11208613; -0.09864074; 0.45360373;
    -0.10414895; -0.18303173; 0.39306646; 0.05457107; -0.19024738; 0.06828192; 0.29422425;
    -0.18672513; -0.23610061; 0.48881179; -0.09731334; -0.05470424; 0.26214565; -0.17978073,
    -0.10337649; 0.10246465; 0.24676284; -0.05835531; 0.06804471; -0.34589734; -0.34035067];

% Grid points to interpolate at: 12x12 points
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-2,1.2,12), linspace(-1.75,0.75,12));

% Interpolation
Z = griddata(points(:,1), points(:,2), values, X, Y, "linear");


Python example code:
import numpy as np
import scipy

# Sample points (x, y): 7x5 = 35 points
points = np.array([
    [-3., -2.], [-2.25, -2.], [-1.5, -2.], [-0.75, -2.], [0., -2.], [0.75, -2.], [1.5, -2.],
    [-3., -1.25], [-2.25, -1.25], [-1.5, -1.25], [-0.75, -1.25], [0., -1.25], [0.75, -1.25], [1.5, -1.25],
    [-3., -0.5], [-2.25, -0.5], [-1.5, -0.5], [-0.75, -0.5], [0., -0.5], [0.75, -0.5], [1.5, -0.5],
    [-3., 0.25], [-2.25, 0.25], [-1.5, 0.25], [-0.75, 0.25], [0., 0.25], [0.75, 0.25], [1.5, 0.25],
    [-3., 1.], [-2.25, 1.], [-1.5, 1.], [-0.75, 1.], [0., 1.], [0.75, 1.], [1.5, 1.]
])

# Data values at the sample points: 35 values
values = np.array([
    0.12702104, -0.24534877, -0.08879096, 0.13749533, 0.2431933, -0.01159269, 0.11705169,
    0.10039714, 0.23370454, 0.0020298, -0.05512349, -0.11208613, -0.09864074, 0.45360373,
    -0.10414895, -0.18303173, 0.39306646, 0.05457107, -0.19024738, 0.06828192, 0.29422425,
    -0.18672513, -0.23610061, 0.48881179, -0.09731334, -0.05470424, 0.26214565, -0.17978073,
    -0.10337649, 0.10246465, 0.24676284, -0.05835531, 0.06804471, -0.34589734, -0.34035067
])

# Interpolation grid: 12x12 points 
x = np.linspace(-2, 1.2, 12)
y = np.linspace(-1.75, 0.75, 12)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Interpolation
Z = scipy.interpolate.griddata(points, values, (X, Y), method='linear')

This is Matlab output.
And this is Python output.
The output values differ greatly. Then I tried to get around it using Delaunay triangulation tool from scipy.spatial together with scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator function:
# # Perform Delaunay triangulation
tri = Delaunay(points, qhull_options='Qbb Qc') #Qt is always enabled
# # Interpolation function
interp = sp.LinearNDInterpolator(points, values)
ZZ = interp(X, Y)

Still no luck. The results are not the same. What would be the reason for this? How can we get the same result from Scipy's griddata() function?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@CrisLuengo My apologies. I have added screenshots (image links) of the outputs. The interpolated values are different at most of the grid points. I guess It's significant errors.

Your input points form a square grid, which makes the Delaunay triangulation ambiguous (i.e. there are multiple, equally valid triangulations). And linear interpolation in between four vertices of a square gives different results depending on how you split that square into two triangles. This might be the cause of the differences, I don't know. Both seem correct interpolations. Since your input is on a grid, you are better off using a grid interpolation method. It'll be a lot faster, and unambiguous.

One way to effectively see this instability is to add a tiny amount of noise to your points (for example, in MATLAB, points+0.001rand(size(points))) a few times, and plot the Z values obtained each time. You'll see very different results. The noise shouldn't really affect the interpolated values this much, but they cause the triangulation to change (each square potentially gets split into two triangles in a different way when adding a tiny bit of noise to the position of the points), and therefore you get a significantly different interpolation result.

Your input points form a square grid, which makes the Delaunay triangulation ambiguous (i.e. there are multiple, equally valid triangulations). And linear interpolation in between four vertices of a square gives different results depending on how you split that square into two triangles. This is likely the most important cause of the differences.
One way to effectively see this instability is to add a tiny amount of noise to the position of your points a few times, and plot the Z values obtained each time. You'll see different results. The positional noise shouldn't really affect the interpolated values this much, but they cause the triangulation to change (each square potentially gets split into two triangles in a different way when adding a tiny bit of noise to the position of the points), and therefore you get a significantly different interpolation results.
I added 0.001 * rand() to each coordinate in MATLAB, and obtained the following four plots:

[I made the plots using surf(X, Y, Z), then rotated the plots manually to look at the surface from above. Alternatively, use imagesc(Z).]
Both MATLAB and Python produce correct interpolations. But since your input is on a grid, you are better off using a grid interpolation method. It'll be a lot faster, and unambiguous (which means you can get essentially the same result in both languages).
If your sample points were randomly scattered, then the Delaunay triangulation would not be ambiguous, and you should get consistent results from implementation to implementation.
